# How can I Fix a Double Free or Corruption Error

Tags: c++

I encounter an error when opening a non-existent printer. My application works fine when a printer is found. But when there is no printer found, I encounter a double free or corruption error.
Below is my code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 200

FILE *pPortFile = NULL;

void Printer::closePrinter()
{
    if (pPortFile != NULL)
    {
        fclose(pPortFile);
        pPortFile = NULL;
    }
}

void Printer::openPrinter(string sPortName)
{
    struct stat tFilest;
    int iFileDescriptor = 0, i = 0;
    char aResponse[BUFSIZE] = {0}, aFName[BUFSIZE];

    ePrinterType_ = UNKNOWN;

    closePrinter();

    pPortFile = popen("find /sys/devices/platform -name lp0 -print", "r");

    if (pPortFile != NULL)
    {
        i = fread(aResponse, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE - 1, pPortFile);

        aResponse[i] = '\0';

        if(i != 0)
        {
            pclose(pPortFile);
            strcpy(aFName, dirname(aResponse));
            strcat(aFName, "/../../idProduct");
            pPortFile = fopen(aFName, "r");            

            if (i != 0 && pPortFile != NULL)
            {
                i = fread(aResponse, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE - 1, pPortFile);
                aResponse[i] = '\0';

                if (strstr(aResponse,"3538"))
                    ePrinterType_ = PRINTER_1;
                else if (strstr(aResponse,"2305"))
                    ePrinterType_ = PRINTER_2;
            }

            fclose(pPortFile);
        }

        pclose(pPortFile);

    }

    if(ePrinterType_ == UNKNOWN)
    {
        cout << "printer not found" << endl;
        throw Exception("Printer not found");
    }
    else
    {
        pPortFile = fopen(sPortName.c_str(), "r+");
        iFileDescriptor = fileno(pPortFile);
    }
}
```

I encounter the double free or corruption (!prev) error after this line:

```
if(ePrinterType == UNKNOWN)
{
    cout << "printer not found" << endl;
    throw Exception("Printer not found");
}
```

I can't find where the error actually occurs. Please help

Comment: Have you tried temporarily removing parts of the code to see if the corruption still occurs? If you can make the code example smaller while retaining the program then it will be easier to spot the bug.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], for example what does `closePrinter` do?

Comment: I modified my original post to add closePrinter()

Comment: You call `fclose(NULL)` if the file open fails, this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: You aren't setting pPortFile to null when closing it but then using `pPortFile != NULL` when desciding to close it again or not

Comment: When I debug the application, I put a cout that will print if pPortFile  is NULL or not. When there is no printer, the app printed that pPortFile is not NULL. I also put a cout to see the value of variable i, then I got 0

Comment: Don't reuse the same variable for multiple purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines - do you really want to do them all - explain why you do them...

```
        pclose(pPortFile);
        ...
        fclose(pPortFile);
    ...
    pclose(pPortFile);
```

Comment: the first pclose should be called because there is another call to fopen. Upon debugging, the first pclose will not be called when there is no printer found. I can remove the last pclose though. But it did not fix the problem.